# Can't use cmd for MySQL server Windows 7

Tags: mysql, windows-7

I just installed MySQL community server on Windows 7, completed the configuration wizard making sure the command line is included but I just can't use it from `cmd`.

Entering mysql or MySql just returns an error that there is no such command.

Does anyone have any advice?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to [add the path](https://web.archive.org/web/20210213041100/http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx) to MySQL to your Windows `PATH`. You will probably need to exit CMD and start it again so the change takes effect.

Or, if you don't want to exit CMD, you can enter the following command at the prompt:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;c:\path\to\mysql
```

substituting the correct directory structure. That command will only affect the current session until it's exited.

Comment: just did that and it did not help :(

Comment: ok, set PATH=%PATH%;c:\path\to\mysql did not work but ADDING PATH FROM MY COMPUTER SETTINGS helped. So now it works!!! Perfect

Comment: @Alex: Does it work if you use the full path to start it at the command line? Something like `c:\prompt> C:\path\to\mysql` (enter the part after the prompt).